# Embedding bash script into makefile

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, gcc, makefile

I want to include some conditional statement into a makefile:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
all: 
        $(g++ -Wall main.cpp othersrc.cpp -o hello)
        @if [[ $? -ne -1 ]]; then \
          echo "Compile failed!"; \
          exit 1; \
        fi
```

But get an error:

> /bin/bash: -c: line 0: conditional binary operator expected /bin/bash:
>   -c: line 0: syntax error near `-1' /bin/bash: -c: line 0:`if [[  -ne -1 ]]; then \' makefile:3: recipe for target 'all' failed make: *** [all] Error 1

How to fix it?

Comment: Ack, no!  Make's usual behavior if g++ fails is to let let g++ write its error messages and then abort.  It looks like you are trying to suppress the normal behavior and write a mostly useless error message to the wrong output stream!  Just call g++, let it write its own error messges, and let make check the return value and abort.

Comment: @williampursell error messages won't be suppressed

Comment: It seems unnecessary to me to limit the portability of your makefile by setting `SHELL = /bin/bash` just so you can use `[[ ... ]]` form conditions... why not use POSIX sh-compliant `if [ $$? -eq 0 ]; ...` and not bother resetting `SHELL`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that each line of a makefile recipe runs in a different shell, so that `$?` of the previous line is unavailable, unless you use [`.ONESHELL`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#One-Shell) option.

A fix without `.ONESHELL`:

```
all: hello
.PHONY: all

hello: main.cpp othersrc.cpp
    g++ -o $@ -Wall main.cpp othersrc.cpp && echo "Compile succeeded." || (echo "Compile failed!"; false)
```

With `.ONESHELL`:

```
all: hello
.PHONY: all

SHELL:=/bin/bash
.ONESHELL:

hello:
    @echo "g++ -o $@ -Wall main.cpp othersrc.cpp"
    g++ -o $@ -Wall main.cpp othersrc.cpp
    if [[ $$? -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo "Compile succeded!"
    else
        echo "Compile failed!"
        exit 1
    fi
```

When `$` needs to be passed into a shell command it must be quoted as `$$` in the makefile (`make` charges you a dollar for passing one dollar, basically). Hence `$$?`.

Comment: cool! But how could I implemented the "else" branch? Say, I want to output "Success at dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss"

Comment: @amplifier Added another branch for you.

Comment: it appears that the only option is to play around with logical operators. But for more complex scenarios, is it possible to use bash inside makefiles, or there's another option, like having sh script calling make? I'm just learning linux scripting

Comment: @amplifier Added a conditional version for you.

Comment: If you use .ONESHELL you don't need the backslashes.  If you don't want to use .ONESHELL (note that's only available in GNU make 4.0 and above) then using the backslashes is sufficient, you don't need .ONESHELL (but you have to add `; \` to the end of the `g++` line as well).

Comment: @MadScientist Very nice feature, thank you. Updated.